# Mixdown introduces strange clicking in one channel

Tags: adobe-audition

Novice question:  My mixdown in **Adobe Audition** is rendered with a clicking out of the right channel.  I don't know where it's coming from or how to get rid of it.  I suspect it might be something like a computer process or wifi.  I've never seen this before and I'm not an audio pro.  Any insight will be very appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by eliminating tracks and/or plugins from your mix to see exactly which track is causing the problem. In fact, mute everything entirely and see if the clicking still occurs. You should be consistent with your mix parameters during this process and mix using full-speed offline mixing if that is possible with audition.

Also experiment with buffer size changes at the asio/core-audio level.

I strongly suspect a plugin is doing this, so identify the track containing the suspect plugin then start testing each of the plugins individually and then remove the offending one.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I narrowed it down to the music files.  Then I put the music on a new track and deleted the track, and everything rendered clean.  I'm not sure why, but it seems like something on that track in Audition introduced these strange clicking noises.  I have no idea what did it but a new track solved the issue.  I'd like to know why though.

Comment: Hmmm <cough>adobe</cough> ... I am not sure either. Strange one that....